# python ISO 8601 format

Tags: python, date, datetime, timestamp

I am pretty new to python below is java code for converting that I wrote for converting a date obj to ISO format. I want similar code for python I have searched a long and tried few solutions but none of them have worked so far.

```
 private String getISOTimestamp(Long timeStamp) {
    Date date = new Date(timeStamp);
    String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
    String isoTS = sdf.format(date);
    return isoTS;
}
```

Comment: Please post one of the solutions that didn't work and explain what's wrong with it.

Comment: yeah sure, I used **last_updated.isoformat()** to get the formated string what I get is the following **2018-01-08T14:21:32**, but what I expected was **2018-01-08T14:21:32Z** there is no trailing Z there, I found this https://bugs.python.org/issue23332 on internet might be relevant.

Comment: The troublesome old date-time classes used here in Java were outmoded years ago, supplanted by the *java.time* classes. `Instant.now().toString()` --> `2018-01-23T12:34:56.123456Z`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
s = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
print now.strftime(s)
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked :)

Comment: saved me thinking about it.. GJ :)